# Want to use the position of the face for controlling a player in javascript

Tags: javascript, webcam, face-detection, face-recognition

I'm trying to write a script in javascript where the position of the face can be used as the position of the player.

So, I have a function for the player to move to the left and a function for the player to move to the right. When the face goes to the left the function going to the left should be called. And the same goes for the right.

At this moment I'm completely stuck and I hope someone can help me out! 
I tried to get it working with the libraries: tracker.js and faceDetection.js but if anyone has another/better option it would be great.

So when the left or right arrow is pressed the function playerMove should be called

```
function playerMove(offset) {
player.pos.x += offset;
if (collide(arena, player)) {
    player.pos.x -= offset;
}
   }



document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
if (event.keyCode === 37) {
    playerMove(-1);
} else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
    playerMove(1);
} else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
    playerDrop();
} else if (event.keyCode === 81) {
    playerRotate(-1);
} else if (event.keyCode === 87) {
    playerRotate(1);
}
});
```

Comment: Please check i have added one example

Answer (score 0):

Here some basic examples you can start with. :-D

```js
const faceImg = document.getElementById("face");
const [TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIFHT, ROTATE_L, ROTATE_R] = [38, 40, 37, 39, 81, 87];
const px = (t) => Number(t.split("px")[0]);
function playerMove([x, y]) {
  y && (faceImg.style.bottom = `${px(faceImg.style.bottom) + y}px`);
  x && (faceImg.style.left = `${px(faceImg.style.left) + x}px`);
}
function rotate(angle) {
  faceImg.className = "";
  faceImg.classList.add(angle);
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === TOP) {
    playerMove([, 50]);
  } else if (event.keyCode === BOTTOM) {
    playerMove([, -50]);
  } else if (event.keyCode === LEFT) {
    playerMove([-50]);
  } else if (event.keyCode === RIFHT) {
    playerMove([50]);
  } else if (event.keyCode === ROTATE_L) {
    rotate("spine_l");
  } else if (event.keyCode === ROTATE_R) {
    rotate("spine_r");
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

}

#face.spine_l {
  -webkit-animation: spin_l 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: spin_l 1s linear;
  animation: spin_l 1s linear;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin_l { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin_l { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin_l { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }

#face.spine_r {
  -webkit-animation: spin_r 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: spin_r 1s linear;
  animation: spin_r 1s linear;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin_r { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin_r { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
@keyframes spin_r { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); transform:rotate(-360deg); } }
```

```html
<pre>TOP | BOTTOM | LEFT | RIGHT | Q | W</pre>
    <div class="container">
        <img id="face"
            src="https://library.kissclipart.com/20180906/kwq/kissclipart-face-icon-clipart-computer-icons-d824d3a7529ee2f5.png"
            alt="">
    </div>
```